# YUM can't resolve dependency even though yum finds the dependent package

Tags: yum, rpm

This is driving me crazy.

Yum is telling me that it can't resolve a dependency even though it finds the dependent RPM.

Yum says that `sri-mcstools = 3.0_3_ge35b2fd-master` is required and that it's available but won't install it.

Why won't yum use the available package?

```
[root@sri-5149-0001 tmp.jLCJVVQt09]# yum --disablerepo '*'  --enablerepo sri-fme downgrade sri-transmitter-3.0_41_gb3e95c5-master
    Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
    This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
    sri-fme                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
    sri-fme/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |  13 kB  00:00:00
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package sri-transmitter.noarch 0:3.0_41_gb3e95c5-master will be a downgrade
    --> Processing Dependency: sri-FlexCpDsp-20-6008-01 = 3.0_10_g99ba8bd-master for package: sri-transmitter-3.0_41_gb3e95c5-master.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: sri-WebGui = 3.0_103_g4c065ee7-master for package: sri-transmitter-3.0_41_gb3e95c5-master.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: sri-filesystem = 3.0_6_g771b0c7-master for package: sri-transmitter-3.0_41_gb3e95c5-master.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: sri-flexcpkintex-02 = 3.0_3_gc037458-master for package: sri-transmitter-3.0_41_gb3e95c5-master.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: sri-mcstools = 3.0_3_ge35b2fd-master for package: sri-transmitter-3.0_41_gb3e95c5-master.noarch
    ---> Package sri-transmitter.noarch 0:3.0_59_g40bf51e-master will be erased
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: sri-transmitter-3.0_41_gb3e95c5-master.noarch (sri-fme)
               Requires: sri-mcstools = 3.0_3_ge35b2fd-master
               Installed: sri-mcstools-3.0_4_g288cb9a-master.noarch (@sri-latest)
                   sri-mcstools = 3.0_4_g288cb9a-master
               Available: sri-mcstools-3.0_3_ge35b2fd-master.noarch (sri-fme)
                   sri-mcstools = 3.0_3_ge35b2fd-master
```

Comment: That suggests that something else requires `sri-mcstools-3.0_4`. What happens if you add `--allowerasing` to your command line?